# undefined function error when calling it in another directory

Tags: php

I have another directory(admin) there i have an index file which require blog file and i got an error its say's Call to undefined function Blog\DB\connect() but what really confuse me is that it never gives me an error when i require it in the root directory files(`index` or `single`) it runs very fine.

**admin/index.php** code:

```
<?php 
require '../blog.php';

view('admin/create');
?>
```

**blog.php** code:

```
    require 'functions.php';
    require 'config/config.php';
    require 'db.php';

     use Blog\DB;
 $conn = DB\connect($config['DB_USERNAME'],$config['DB_PASSWORD'],$config['DATABASE']);
 if (!$conn) die('Could not Connect');
```

I have spent 2 days finding the reason for this error if anyone can enlighten that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the correct directory. If you're not in the directory right below where the file is, you need to go up another level

```
require '../../blog.php';
```

Or, you can specify the path starting from DOCUMENT_ROOT, so that you never have to calculate how many levels to go up:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/blog.php'
```

Comment: ../../ - this means up two directories right? thank your your response

Comment: Correct. Each `../` is up one directory.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `require` uses the calling scripts folder (which is `admin/`).
Change your `require` in blog.php to:

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/functions.php';
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.php';
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/db.php';
```

Using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` only works it the script is called through a web server and not from CLI.

Comment: thank you so much for your respnse i really appreciate it , can u tell me about more about this 'calling script folder' its the 1st time i heard this terms.

Comment: it works like magic .. i understand that using dirname it gives the  parent directory path ,,but i dont understnd why  it wont work using just require

Comment: Read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php (include and require works the same in this regard). And if it works, feel free to accept this answer. :)

Comment: i have read this already but i never take it seriously..gues i have miss some important  details...u dont know how how much you help me with this one..i wish i could return the favor to you sirr in the future.. have a good day

Comment: Well, you could allways start by accepting this answer so others will know that this issue is resolved.